# How to view and download the Clustered data from Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have csv file containing 50k records, my Table format looks like below. I created stage in `Snowflake` to load that file. Next,I have 7 different regions, so I would like create 7 different csv file based on region and download those CSV files to my computer. For this I used `CLUSTER BY` function in `Snowflake` to create cluster based on Region. I am new to snowflake so not sure where should I go from here ? How to view and download the clustered data from `Snowflake` ? Below is my code so far

Thanks in advance for your time and efforts!

[image]

**Code so far**

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 CLUSTER BY (REGION)
```

Comment: try reading https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html AND/OR https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-considerations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you use clustering in Snowflake so you may want to undo that.

To create a CSV file per region on your table, you can do it interactively in Snowflake UI, just run a query per region and download the result set.

```
select * from TABLE1 where REGION = 'A';
```

And then there is a download button in the Result pane.

**Classic UI:**

[image]

**Snowsight UI:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I thought  Clustering can help me here, but seems like it's not the case. Thanks!